# Is it possible that time-stamps in python logging file are not chronological in a multi-threaded system?

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I have written my code  in an event driven python API. `on_tick()` is called by the API asynchronously and within this function lies my code. Between two consecutive calls to `on_tick()`, my processing usually finishes, but sometimes takes longer. I have logged inside `on_tick()` at three places, and expect those lines to be logged in chronological order. But sometimes I see next line having a log time less than that of the previous line! How on earth is that possible?

```
def on_tick(ticks):

    logging.info('entered inside on_tick()')

    tens_of_lines;

    logging.info('calling strategy controller from on_tick()') 

    strategy_controller()

    logging.info('returning from on_tick()') 

    return
```

on grepping a few lines from the log file, I see:

```
2019-01-14 09:25:17,434 entered inside on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:17,452 calling strategy controller from on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:18,241 returning from on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:18,252 entered inside on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:18,294 calling strategy controller from on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:18,956 returning from on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:18,957 entered inside on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:19,994 calling strategy controller from on_tick()
=> 2019-01-14 09:25:19,685 returning from on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:19,696 entered inside on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:19,722 calling strategy controller from on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:20,270 returning from on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:20,280 entered inside on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:20,315 calling strategy controller from on_tick()
2019-01-14 09:25:20,563 returning from on_tick()
```

I have purposely highlighted the line that is problematic with =>. It is printed later, but has an earlier time-stamp. That too by hundreds of milliseconds! I cannot even think of scenarios where this is possible. Also, if next call to `on_tick()` comes before previous call finishes, does the previous call finish first, keeping the next call's thread suspended? Can you please help ?

EDIT: I tried changing the `logging.info()` command to `logfile.write()` where `logfile` is handle of log file obtained via `open` command. The times I wrote into files are obtained by `datetime.now()`. BINGO! This fixed the problem. Now all logged lines have chronological times. To understand why this is happening, I kept both `logging.info` and `logfile.write` intact at consecutive lines, and wrote them into two different files. What I realized is that `logging.info` is printing wrong times sometimes! And those wrong times are off my exactly 1 second! For example, in the above log the only wrong time is the one above => line i.e. 19,994 should actually have been 18,994.

Not sure why this is happening. I am using the below configuration for logging.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('some_random_string')

#The below is done to make sure the vendor's API doesn't mess with my logs
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename='log_file_name.log',level=logging.INFO)

#Change the logging time to India time
def customTime(*args):
    utc_dt = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())
    my_tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")
    converted = utc_dt.astimezone(my_tz)
    return converted.timetuple()

logging.Formatter.converter = customTime
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that log messages get written to the log strictly in the order they were generated, especially if multiple threads are contending on the same logging mechanism. So I would trust the timestamps more than the order of lines in the file. And unless you're using a lock somewhere that you're not showing, nothing prevents multiple copies of the `on_tick` function from running at the same time on different threads.

Comment: I haven't used lock anywhere. The call to on_tick() might be using locks, which is invisible to me. But if your point of trusting the time-stamps more than the order of printing is correct, then 19.685 (returning *) line happened after 18.957 (entered *) line. How is it possible that we enter and exit without calling strategy controller?

Comment: Most likely you have multiple overlapping invocations, especially since you aren't using locks. Allocate a `threading.Lock` somewhere, and use `with my_lock:` at the top of `on_tick` and you should see the invocations serialize. (This means that whatever is *calling* `on_tick` will be blocked while `on_tick` is running, but that sounds like what you want.)

Comment: That's assuming that what you actually have is multiple *threads* and not multiple *processes*. If you're using a WSGI container that forks, it's probably the latter -- in which case you'll need a more complicated locking mechanism. `multiprocessing.Lock` might work for you, or might not, depending on how your code is executing.

Comment: Please see my latest edit. logging.info() is printing wrong times sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be that one thread is blocking the file from being written.
You could bypass this problem by using a threadsafe queue from which the log information is written.
The result would be that your threads don't write/block your file directly.

Comment: Assuming it's a `logging.handlers.FileHandler` that's writing the file, that should already be covered, right?

Comment: yes, it is logging.handlers.FileHandler that's writing the file.